# How to find which column is unable to cast DBNull to String?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, logging

Using Entity Framework to query a MySQL database, one of my tables is giving the error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.` I know if I can figure out which column is giving me the error I can fix it, but I can't seem to find any way to get EF to give me the column name. I've inspected all the columns in the code and find no issues; the data in the database doesn't have any gaps in the required fields; I figured out how to set the logging to `Trace` in my appsettings.json, but aside from showing me the query it sends to the database, I don't see any change in the information that gets logged: it still just says `Unable to cast object of 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.`

Is there any way to get EF to tell me what column it is having trouble with? The only next step I can think of is turning off Just My Code and hoping a deep dive into the source won't get too confusing.

Comment: Try with 'Nullable Reference types'. It's alllows to configure you optional fields are nuallable. for example                                                                                                                        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    // Required by convention
    public string LastName { get; set; }     // Required by convention
    public string? MiddleName { get; set; }  // Optional by convention

Comment: @PrasadRamireddy The issue is that I don't know which column is not set properly.

Comment: Recreate the query in SQL and run it against your database in a query tool like LinqPad or MSSME. Look for unexpected null values.  Or try removing columns from the query until it works. Other than that... we don't have your code or your database, not much more we can do.

Comment: @Corey: I have edited the title of the question to clarify exactly what help is being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this place: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/

specifically i think You can find this bit useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging#detailed-query-exceptions

try turning on detailed query exceptions logging for more details

Comment: I would love to accept this as the answer, but I accidentally found the column a different way before I had a chance to try the excellent suggestions in your link. Upvoting at least.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to try T. Nielsen's suggestion after I finished fixing all the nullable issues that popped up when I enabled nullable reference type checking; but that accidentally led to an alternate way of finding which column wasn't set the way I thought it was: I set up a constructor on the class containing only the fields that were required, and the compiler told me `Non-nullable property 'MyProblemColumn' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.` Which was exactly the reason I was trying to find it.

Comment: I am glad that you managed to solve Your problem, always feels better when we find stuff ourselves. Your question was how to make EF tell you, your 'solution' doesn't address the problem using EF :) so the question "to get EF to give me the column name" is not answered you just solved the problem B-),
though thanks for upvote and happy coding there :)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I found. To find a column with this exception, you need to mark one by one the **string** (or type what you need) type fields in the model with a decorator **[NotMapped]** like this:

`[NotMapped] public string? SelectedValueIDs { get; set; }`

When the error disappears, this is the exception line